# Emulate click on leaflet map item

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Having the Leaflet [Choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) i have to emulate a click event on a specific map area. For example:
i have to have a function like `clickOnMapItem(itemId)` that will click on a map area which is defined by the following code

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"05","properties":{"name":"Arkansas","density":56.43},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...}
```

where **"id":"05"** is the id I need to click on

The rest of my code is as in the example:

state-data.js:

```
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359 and so on
```

html:

...header ommited

```
<!-- language:lang-html -->
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script src="dist/leaflet.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="us-states.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

            var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
                key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707',
                styleId: 22677
            }).addTo(map);


            // control that shows state info on hover
            var info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
                    : 'Hover over a state');
            };

            info.addTo(map);


            // get color depending on population density value
            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
                       d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
                       d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
                       d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                       d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                       d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
                       d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                                  '#FFEDA0';
            }

            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
                };
            }
            //ON HOVER HANDLER
            function highlightFeature(e) {
                var layer = e.target;
                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    dashArray: '',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            var geojson;

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function zoomToFeature(e) {

                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }
            //setting click handlers
            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }

            geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                    labels = [],
                    from, to;

                for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);


        </script>
    </body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorry, it's a 3 years old question, but I will try to answer it here:

First, update your code below:

```
//setting click handlers
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: zoomToFeature
  });
  //add this line
  layer._leaflet_id = feature.id;
}
```

The new line above will 'assign' your geoJSON's 'id' as your layer's leaflet_id,
then make a new function like this :

```
function clickOnMapItem(itemId) {
    var id = parseInt(itemId);
    //get target layer by it's id
    var layer = geojson.getLayer(id);
    //fire event 'click' on target layer 
    layer.fireEvent('click');  
}
```

So, there's no need to populate any coordinate at all!!!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 11):

To add to @snkashis: `fireEvent` will only work if you input the right Types.
That would mean doing this:

```
    var latlngPoint = new L.LatLng(x, y);
    map.fireEvent('click', {
      latlng: latlngPoint,
      layerPoint: map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlngPoint),
      containerPoint: map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlngPoint)
    });
```

You can also do this for a specific marker/layer whatever if it's added to the map.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to emulate a click event? Why not use Leaflet's `fireEvent` like `map.fireEvent('click',{latlng:[x,y]})`

You probably need to fill in layerPoint and containerPoint into the object's parameters.

See http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#mouse-event

Comment: I found that the event argument does not have the `layer` property: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44053812/688080