# Fill e.layer when firing events manually

Tags: events, leaflet

I am using a [`L.vectorGrid.protobuf`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) layer (named as `pbfLayer`) to display vector tiles, and I want to trigger click events by `pbfLayer.fileEvent('click', {latlng: <some coordinate>})`. But if in this way the event argument `e` will only have properties `latlng`, `target`, and `type`, while if triggered manually by mouse clicking it will have more properties including `layer`.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ziyuang/dfekwzhd/

Every time a click event is triggered, the console will print the event argument `e`. A screenshot of console output is as follow, if I first trigger an event manually by clicking and then by programming, using the same coordinate:

[image: demo-points]

Is there a way to find and fill other properties of `e`, so that `fireEvent` can perfectly mimic a clicking? Thank you.

**Update 1** (https://jsfiddle.net/ziyuang/dfekwzhd/4/):

I tried @IvanSanchez's [prosthetic-hand](https://github.com/Leaflet/prosthetic-hand), but still not working. The code added is

```
var crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
var rambaut_lake_latlng = L.latLng(40.99842740667731,-74.16458129882814);
var rambaut_lake_point = crs.latLngToPoint(rambaut_lake_latlng , map.getZoom());
var southwest_point = crs.latLngToPoint(map.getBounds()._southWest, map.getZoom());
var x = rambaut_lake_point.x - southwest_point.x;
var y = map.getSize().y - (southwest_point.y - rambaut_lake_point.y);
console.log([x, y])

var hand = new Hand();
var finger = hand.growFinger('mouse');
finger.moveTo(x, y, 0).down().up();
```

Manually clicking will create a popup of "Rambaut Lake" but I don't see any popup on the page.

**Update 2**: I finally get this done by using [happen](https://github.com/tmcw/happen). 
In my case, I have to

```
var canvas = document.elementFromPoint(left, top);
$(canvas).happen({type: 'click', clientX: left, clientY: top});
```

And neither `$('#map').happen({type: 'click', clientX: left, clientY: top})` nor using jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on the found `canvas` works for me.

Comment: Cross post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240938/fill-e-layer-when-firing-events-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to «perfectly mimic a click», then you should [create and dispatch a synthetic `click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) in the DOM. This is what libraries like [`happen`](https://github.com/tmcw/happen) and [`prosthetic-hand`](https://github.com/Leaflet/prosthetic-hand) do.

Events dispatched in that way will trigger Leaflet's event handling logic, just as if the event were a real one.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, I am using your Leaflet.VectorGrid and it's great! If it were svg I could have used your [Leaflet.CheapLayerAt](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.CheapLayerAt).

Comment: If you have time can you also check [my other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/240969/97502), about obtaining features inside a rectangle? Thank you.